# i cant to run geth file to mining and generate on raspberry-pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, blockchain, ethereum

i create ethereum private network on window and raspi to mininig and run node but i get some problem

[raspi stuck in unlocked account process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbNhV.png)

first problem raspi stuck in unlocked account process when i run Geth file to mining and generate dag (i try to use pc window and it can generate DAG success [in picture2])
[window10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPuYy.png)

second problem 
i cant generate dag and always have Error Code
"Failed to generate mapped ethash dataset epoch=0 err="cannot allocate memory"
runtime: out of memory: cannot allocate 2147483648-byte block (128679936 in use)"
i dont know raspi's RAM or sd card is not enough

i use raspberry pi 3 model B

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggests to replace POW with Proof of Authority.